# How to finish the multithreaded programming problem

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have the following task:

"Port. Ships enter the port to unload / load containers. The number of containers currently in the port and on the ship must be non-negative and exceed the specified capacity of the vessel and the port capacity. There are several berths in the port. One berth can stand ship. The ship may load at berth, unload or perform both operations."

You cannot use the synchronized keyword.

I organized the stream of ships. Made it impossible for the number of containers currently on the ship to be greater than the carrying capacity of the ship. But I can't figure out how to do this: the number of containers currently in port, which must be non-negative and greater than the specified port capacity. I also can't figure out how to make the ship load at the pier, unload or perform both operations?

Ship.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Ship extends Thread {

private static final boolean[] PARKING_PLACES = new boolean[5];

private static final Semaphore SEMAPHORE = new Semaphore(5, true);

private int idShip;
private int currentNumOfContains;
private int maxNumOfContains;
private ReentrantLock locker;

Ship(int idShip, int currentNumOfContains, int maxNumOfContains, ReentrantLock locker) {
    this.idShip = idShip;
    this.currentNumOfContains = currentNumOfContains;
    this.maxNumOfContains = maxNumOfContains;
    this.locker = locker;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (currentNumOfContains <= maxNumOfContains) {
        System.out.printf("Ship №%d sailed to the pier.\n", idShip);
        try {

            SEMAPHORE.acquire();

            int parkingNumber = -1;

            locker.lock();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

                    if (!PARKING_PLACES[i]) {
                        PARKING_PLACES[i] = true;
                        parkingNumber = i;
                        System.out.printf("Ship №%d moored at berth %d.\n", idShip, i);
                        break;
                    }
            } finally {
                locker.unlock();
            }

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            locker.lock();
            try {
                PARKING_PLACES[parkingNumber] = false;
            } finally {
                locker.unlock();
            }

            SEMAPHORE.release();
            System.out.printf("Ship №%d left the pier.\n", idShip);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
    } else System.out.printf("Ship №%d drowned due to overload.\n", idShip);
}
}
```

Port.java

```
public class Port {

private int countOfDock;
private int maxNumOfContainers;
private int currentNumOfContainers;

public Port(int countOfDock, int maxNumOfContainers, int currentNumOfContainers, boolean freePlace) {
    this.countOfDock = countOfDock;
    this.maxNumOfContainers = maxNumOfContainers;
    this.currentNumOfContainers = currentNumOfContainers;
}
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ReentrantLock locker = new ReentrantLock();

    new Ship(1, 90, 100, locker).start();
    Thread.sleep(400);
    new Ship(2, 190, 100, locker).start();
    Thread.sleep(400);
    new Ship(3, 1, 100, locker).start();
    Thread.sleep(400);
    new Ship(4, 48, 100, locker).start();
    Thread.sleep(400);
    new Ship(5, 200, 100, locker).start();
    Thread.sleep(400);
}
}
```

Can anyone help? I'm just at a dead end)

Comment: It does not make sense that the number of containers in port must *exceed* the port's capacity.  That's inconsistent with the meaning of "capacity".  I presume that a "not" was somewhere dropped from the problem description.  I.e. the number of containers in port must *not* exceed the port capacity, and the number on any ship must *not* exceed that ship's capacity.  Also, that makes the container counts bounded on both sides. As presented in the question, they are not bounded above.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it does say the total capacity of the port _and_ ship so it so it might be correct. That is if the port capacity is 100 then there will be > 100 containers in total on the ship and in the port.

Comment: I disagree, @JoakimDanielson. I'm not confident that I've guessed the intention correctly, but the problem as presented is nonsensical, even if you interpret it as talking about the total number of contains in the port and on the ship(s).  And I note that it is by no means clear to me that your interpretation of which number of contains is meant is the intended one.